# What's the fastest way to redirect to a different URL?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect a specific directory on my server to a completely different URL.  Am currently using:

```html
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh"  CONTENT="0; https://anotherserver/index.html">
```

which is still slow.

So to be clear I don't want to redirect `www.example.com`. But I do want to redirect `www.example.com/acme`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have htaccess as a tag but no reference to it in your post.

**For a quick redirect from old server to new server**

```
Redirect /acme/index.html www.MyOtherServer.com/
```

Be careful if SEO is a factor. Not a good practice to use redirects improperly without 301 or 302

Updated because I misread first time around.

Comment: Thank you.  Making sure that if I use 301 robots will get the info from the new link and not the old.

Comment: @SergioD.Caplan that is correct. 301 represents a permanent redirect and 302 a temporary. So this is what you would want Redirect 301 /acme/index.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage.html

Comment: Jut a follow up, is there a limit to the number of redirects I can make?

Comment: @SergioD.Caplan not as long as each redirect is unique.

Comment: Actually I would say this is wrong. You need a URL as target, not just a string that _might_ resemble a host name. So I would suggest `Redirect 301 /acme/index.html https://example.com/newpage.html`

Comment: @arkascha he already knows that from his post using https://anotherserver/index.html the http gets cut out from SO not me at least on my posts.

Comment: Actually the URL scheme is _not_ hidden by SO if you quote it correctly as you can see in my comment. But I originally referred to the answer your phrased, not your comment. The same issue exists in the answer. And I think it is irrelevant if "the OP already knows", answers should get fixed even after acceptance, since they are preserved and read by others who "do _not_ know that"...